# Serialize flats objects of Java pojo to structured/nested json using Gson or Retrofit

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit2

I have a Java class with fields annotated (dot separated) with expected JSON field names and I want to serialize this to nested JSON using Gson or retrofit convertors.

note: Deserialization is not required.

**Java Class**

```
public class InputData {
    public String type = "Usage";
    public String timeframe = "custom";

    @SerializedName("timePeriod.from")
    public String from = "2022-07-14T00:00:00+00:00";

    @SerializedName("timePeriod.to")
    public String to = "2022-07-26T23:59:59+00:00";
}
```

**Expected JSON**

```
{
    "type": "Usage",
    "timeframe": "custom",
    "timePeriod" {
        "from": "2022-07-14T00:00:00+00:00",
        "to": "2022-07-26T23:59:59+00:00"
    }
}
```

I have tried a custom serializer but could convert primitive types to objects in JSON.

I have been attempting TypeAdapterFactory to parse the annotations but there I could not read the value of the fields

Any help would be much appreciated!

I have a function which converts to HashMap from given field name and value

```
private static HashMap<String, Object> convertToObj(String key, String value) {
        HashMap<String, Object> root = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Object> m = root;
        String[] parts = key.split("\\.");
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            String part = parts[i];
            if (i == parts.length - 1) {
                // At last part so put value
                m.put(part, value);
            } else {
                // Before last part so put map
                Map<String, Object> mm = (Map<String, Object>) m.get(part);
                if (mm == null) {
                    mm = new HashMap<>();
                    m.put(part, mm);
                }
                m = mm;
            }
        }
        return root;
    }
```

Comment: Would it be possibly to adjust your `InputData` class to match the JSON data? Otherwise, as you have mentioned, you would need to use reflection to inspect the fields and their annotations and implement the flattening. That would most likely be possible, but if might be bit complicated.